# Как ввести число не менее 12 знаков до запятой и 12 знаков после

Tags: qt

Как ввести число не менее 12 знаков до запятой??? 12 знаков после я понял как создать.

```
ui->lE_z1->setValidator(new QRegExpValidator(QRegExp("^(\\-|)([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\\.)[0-9]{12}"), this));
```